# How implement dynamic required for ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-required

Let say that there is a collection with key-value content. A user can edit values and keys. But when user clicks `Save` button server can return that collection should contain some required key-values. The question - how to do this effectively?

At first glance it needs just to merge names collection from server into already loaded. But this leads to changing content and after user click `Cancel` he views modified collection which actually should not be modified

Also calls `simulateServerValidation` (see jsfiddle example) during page loading is not a solution because `key-values` can be added/removed during editing or user can load page now and start (or finish) editing some minutes later.

For me the main problem is to render/add new key without object modification. E.g. if server return new `keys`, angular draw new inputs, then user simply can click `Cancel` and see non edited values. But when he needs to edit he just fill new inputs. How to do that?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/C_h_e_r_r_y/dgy3w6xn/)

Comment: Not clear. Maybe add concrete code/html to understand what you need better?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll added this a bit later.

Comment: Question was rewritten. Also I added jsfiddle link.